Converting UTC time in model to Local time in view
I have a C# model that includes a list of items, and each item has a DateTime property containing a time that is represented as UTC.
I need to render those times to the UI, which is a cshtml page, and the times should be in local time for the browser.
I am a back-end engineer, very unfamiliar with UI work, but I believe that in order to do this I should pass the C# value through a JavaScript function that does the conversion within the context of the browser.
I would like to return the local DateTime value to the cshtml page so that it can be formatted through the same set of standard converters that are used within the project.
My JavaScript function is as follows:
function convertUTCDateTimeToLocalDateTime(date) {
  var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);

  var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  var hours = date.getHours();

  newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

  return newDate;
}

Within the cshtml file I have a 'scripts' section as follows:
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/datetime-conversion.js" asp-add-nonce="true"></script>
}

Within the body of the cshtml file I would like to be able to do something like this:
@foreach (var thing in things)
{
    DateTime utcTime = thing.DateTimeInUtc;
    DateTime localTime = convertUTCDateTimeToLocalDateTime(@utcTime);

    // Render localTime
}

I've read as much as I can, but I can't find the answer to this so I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, or my syntax is wrong.

Fun-fact: web-servers have no idea what the user's browser's local timezone is (because browsers don't declare their timezone in their HTTP request headers). You can only infer it - or rely on pre-shared knowledge (e.g. by tying it into your user-accounts system) - or use JS to get the user's timezone from Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone and store it in a cookie so that all future requests will get it right.

var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);  <-- You're already including the getTimezoneOffset() here, why are you applying it again when you do newDate.setHours(hours - offset); ?

@Dai Truth be told, I nicked it from another SO post.  But at the minute I can't even get it to return a value for formatting, I'm a way off working out whether the returned value is correct.

Random suggestion: consider using the HTML <time> element when doing server-side rendering and have a simple JS script that (onDOMContentLoaded) scans the whole page for any <time> elements and then applies a local adjustment, or perhaps on-click?

If you have to do this entirely on the client-side, moment.js will help you. If it's possible to save the offset from the browser on the server-side, then use DateTimeOffset in c#, and pass the ISO string to the client.
